# Python read csv single specific cell

Tags: python, pandas, cell

Im trying to read just a single cell, in order to bring in the date to use elsewhere.
Using pandas I get an error If I try to do this, generally just that the dataframe cant be read because it expects a workable dataframe and not a single cell value prior to the actual convertable dataframe far below the initial line. How can I just get the cell i.e. [A2]

[CSV example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JPoI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, pandas is not very good at files with inconsistent format (like varying number of columns).  For that purpose, I recommend you should use [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) the standard library.

The code below should give you the desired value.

```py
import csv

row = 2; col = 1  # A2 = (2,1) cell
with open("yourfile.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for i in range(row):
        row = next(reader)
    value = row[col-1]  # because python index starts at zero
print(value)
```

Demo (using string instead of a file):

```py
import csv

row = 2; col = 1  # A2 = (2,1) cell
input_str = ["a,b", "c,d,e", "f,g,h,i"]

reader = csv.reader(input_str)
for i in range(row):
    row = next(reader)
value = row[col-1]  # because python index starts at zero
print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to access csv like a two-dimensional object you need to convert it first to 2D python List

```
import csv

with open("imdb.csv") as f:
    csv_as_list = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=","))
    print(csv_as_list[3][2])
```

The format for accessing element is `csv_as_list[row_index][column_index]`.